# (Android Studio) my Bundle.getSerializable for login form is null at starter

Tags: android

Here is my **Login Activity** code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRegisPassword);
    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    Button registerNow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterNow);


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ArrayList<String> data = (ArrayList<String>) extras.getSerializable("array_list");  //this code always null at starter

            if(extras!=null) {
                if (username.getText().toString().length() == 0 || password.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password must be filled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!data.contains(username.getText().toString()) || !data.contains(password.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password must be registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        }
    });



    registerNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

  }
```

}

And this is my **register form** code.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 ArrayList<String> addArray = new ArrayList<String>();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRegisUsername);
    final EditText Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRegisPassword);
    final EditText ConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtConfirmPassword);
    final EditText FullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRegisFullName);
    final EditText PhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRegisPhone);
    final EditText DateOfBirth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRegisDateOfBirth);
    final EditText Address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRegisAddress);
    final RadioGroup rdGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    RadioButton rdMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdMale);
    RadioButton rdFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdFemale);
    Button Register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    Button LoginNow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginNow);


    Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(Username.getText().toString().length()==0 || Password.getText().toString().length()==0 ||
                    ConfirmPassword.getText().toString().length()==0 || FullName.getText().toString().length()==0 ||
                    PhoneNumber.getText().toString().length()==0 || DateOfBirth.getText().toString().length()==0 ||
                    Address.getText().toString().length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "All fields must be filled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(Username.getText().toString().length()<5 || Username.getText().toString().length()>20){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Username must be between 5 and 20 characters.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(Password.getText().toString().length()<5 || Password.getText().toString().length()>20){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password must be between 5 and 20 characters.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(!ConfirmPassword.getText().toString().equals(Password.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Confirm Password must be match with Password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(!Address.getText().toString().endsWith(" Street")){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Address must be ends with “Street”.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(addArray.contains(Username.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Username already registered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                addArray.add(Username.getText().toString());
                addArray.add(Password.getText().toString());
                //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegisterActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("array_list", addArray);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    LoginNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

please help me, i'm trying everything but can't solved my problem.
"my login form always forced to close because the value in register form still null at start", but if i register the user data for first, the login form works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether your bundle is null or not, then use it.
Secondly, you should use getStringArrayList instead of getSerializable as follows :

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        if(extras!=null) {
    ArrayList<String> data = extras.getStringArrayList("array_list");  // use getStringArrayList instead of getSerializable

                    if (username.getText().toString().length() == 0 || password.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password must be filled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (!data.contains(username.getText().toString()) || !data.contains(password.getText().toString())) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password must be registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: ah thanks u helped me about null exception problem, but your solution above make my validation: edit text must be filled, etc.. not working ahahah

Comment: Have you made any changes in your code, I guess there is a problem in your validation

Comment: i just made some modification on my code now based from your solution, it is worked now. Btw how to comment code in comment? i'm new here

Answer (score 0):

i have checked your code as per my debug report your list object is getting null when getting the list back.
you can also try @Suraj Makhija code. otherwise i am telling you
To resolve this issue you can approach 2 way.

i) you can use  `ArrayList<CharSequence>()` instead of `ArrayList<String>()` this is the most simple why because it don't require any additional type casting to get it again which you have done here which cause NullPointerException some times.

```
ArrayList<String> data = (ArrayList<String>) extras.getSerializable("array_list");
```

there is two method to set data and get data from intent -->
    `// dataList type is ArrayList<CharSequence>()`
    `intent.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(KEY,dataList)`
    `intent.getCharSequenceArrayExtra(KEY)//in return you will get list here`

ii) 2nd is as a suggestion i will tell you to use a modeled array list with getter and setter it will help you much more instead of simple String type array list.

Example :

```
public class KeyValueModel implements Parcelable {
String mKey,mValue;

protected KeyValueModel(Parcel in) {
    mKey = in.readString();
    mValue = in.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(mKey);
    dest.writeString(mValue);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<KeyValueModel> CREATOR = new Creator<KeyValueModel>() {
    @Override
    public KeyValueModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new KeyValueModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValueModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new KeyValueModel[size];
    }
};

public String getmKey() {
    return mKey;
}

public void setmKey(String mKey) {
    this.mKey = mKey;
}

public String getmValue() {
    return mValue;
}

public void setmValue(String mValue) {
    this.mValue = mValue;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but umm.. maybe this code too expert for me ahaha, i'm new in android develop in this semester, still learning. But my problem is fixed by a comment above

Answer (score 0):

so, this is for my solution, and worked.. hope will help the others

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(extras!=null) { //this is for if i've register an account before (aka not null again after register).
                ArrayList<String> data = extras.getStringArrayList("array_list");
                if (username.getText().toString().length() == 0 || password.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password must be filled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!data.contains(username.getText().toString()) || !data.contains(password.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password must be registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else { //this for null condition
                ArrayList<String> nullData = new ArrayList<String>();
                nullData.add(username.getText().toString());
                nullData.add(password.getText().toString());

                if (username.getText().toString().length() == 0 || password.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password must be filled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!nullData.equals(null)){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password must be registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```